# Parsing contents of a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, dataframe, parsing

I've a dataframe and one of its columns has strings stored in it. I want to parse the contents of the string to create additional columns.

Example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'entry1': "30&deg;C, pH 7.5, text some suff", 'entry2': 'pH and temperature not available'}, index=[0])
df = df.transpose()
print(df)

pH = []
temp = []
for l in list(df[0]):
    for x in l.split(","):
        pH.append(x) if 'pH' in x else np.NAN
        temp.append(x) if '&deg;C' in x else np.NAN

print(pH)
print(temp)
```

I've tried the above but I haven't been successful in obtaining the end result.

Expected result:

```
df >
                                       0   pH   temp
entry1  30&deg;C, pH 7.5, text some suff   7.5  30
entry2  pH and temperature not available
```

I've not been able to correctly parse the pH values in the code sample provided above, I think regular expression has to be used. Suggestions on how to obtain the expected output will be highly appreciated.

EDIT:
Based on the comment given below, I'm adding a few more test cases. Please check the following possibilities.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'entry1': "30&deg;C, pH 7.5, text some suff", 'entry2': 'pH and temperature not available', 'entry3': "pH 14.0, 30.7&deg; C", 'entry4': "30.7&deg; C", 'entry5': "pH 5.0", 'entry6': "stuff", 'entry7': "stuff before, 30&deg;C, pH 7.5, text some suff"}, index=[0])
```

Comment: Are ` "xx&deg;C` and `pH` always the first and second elements in each `entry`?

Comment: No, it could be in any position. Thanks for the response

Comment: So you should edit your question with a couple more examples showing that. Also, if it's possible that degree is available but ph is not (or the other way around) you should show that too or indicate that it's impossible.

Comment: @JackFleeting Kindly have a look at the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use two `.str.extract` calls with the following regexps:

**pH**: `\bpH\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`
**temp**: `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)&deg;\s*C\b`

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/t6GjwE/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/t6GjwE/3)

**Details**

- `\bpH\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`: `pH` is matched as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary), then 0 or more whitespaces are matched with `\s*`, and then an integer or float value is captured into Group 1 (the actual output of `str.extract`) (`\d+` matches one or more digits and `(?:\.\d+)?` matches an optional sequence of a dot and 1+ digits)
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)&deg;\s*C\b`: this matches and captures an integer or float into Group 1 first, then matches a `&deg;` substring, `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespaces and then `C` is matched as a whole word.

Python usage example:

```
df['pH'] = df[0].str.extract(r'\bpH\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=False)
df['temp'] = df[0].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)&deg;\s*C\b', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                     0    pH  temp
entry1                30&deg;C, pH 7.5, text some suff   7.5    30
entry2                pH and temperature not available   NaN   NaN
entry3                            pH 14.0, 30.7&deg; C  14.0  30.7
entry4                                     30.7&deg; C   NaN  30.7
entry5                                          pH 5.0   5.0   NaN
entry6                                           stuff   NaN   NaN
entry7  stuff before, 30&deg;C, pH 7.5, text some suff   7.5    30
```